# Initializing T& with a default value

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the following allocator class:

```
 template <class BackingAllocator>
    class ScratchAllocator : public Allocator // Allocator is non-copyable
    {
    public:
        ScratchAllocator(size_t size, BackingAllocator& ref_allocator);
        ScratchAllocator(size_t size);
        ~ScratchAllocator();

        // Allocate, Free, ...


    private:
        BackingAllocator& m_backingAllocator;

        char* m_begin;
        char* m_end;
        char* m_allocate;
        char* m_free;
    };
```

I would like to be able to create a `ScratchAllocator` by providing a backing allocator reference in the constructor(in this case it's a `MallocAllocator`), or not , in which case the backing allocator's default constructor is called.

The issue is that I'm storing the backing allocator as a **reference** in my class, so if I attempt to give it a default value in the constructor, it will be destroyed by the end of the scope.

A possible solution that I thought of was to allocate an allocator, but the problem is that it's not necessary if a backing allocator was provided.

Any ideas?

**Edit:**

I cannot take the BackingAllocator by value because assignment operators are disabled in Allocator classes.

Comment: Why do you store the allocator by reference instead of by value?

Comment: Take `BackingAllocator` by value.

Comment: @JVApen Made an edit.

Comment: Well, one solution would be to have the default allocation be a singleton so that you can initialize the reference with it if desired. The other alternative would be to have a member that tell if the allocator is owned. It could be a `std::unique_ptr<MallocAllocator>`. In that case, you just have to put that member first and use the constructor that does not take any allocator.

Comment: @Phil1970 keep in mind that this is a simple **allocator** class. I don't want to pull in any dependencies like the stl; that's why i'm writing a custom allocator class in the first place.

Comment: Then write your own code to replace `std::unique_ptr` which is trivial here since you would only need to call delete from the destructor (assuming that your class is not copiable). If your class need to support copy, then you either have to use the singleton solution or use a `std::shared_ptr` or do your own reference counting (I do not recommend it)... By the way `<memory>` is header only dependency so it is not that bad. It might increase compile time a bit for files that use the allocator but it should not be problematic.

Comment: @Phil1970 thx for the advice :) I'll definitely look into that.